# Compile vtd-xml linux?

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

How should one compile vtd-xml for java on a linux box? I downloaded the project from sourceforge, but it only comes with a .bat script. I set classpath to reference the jar file, but I get all sorts of symbol not found errors when I try to run my compile my own script. I think vtd-xml needs to be compiled as a project before I can use it in other scripts, but I don't know how. I'm new to java...

Comment: DId you resolve the first issue?

Comment: Can you show me the log for your symbol error?

Answer (score 0):

you should not. Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/files/vtd-xml/ximpleware_2.12/VTD-XML%20Standard%20Edition/ximpleware-2.12-java.zip/download

And download the zip, it has been verified to work...

Just put vtd-xml_2-12.jar in your classpath

> Disclaimer: I am the author of vtd-xml.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12278139)

Comment: why are you deleting a legit answer to a valid question??

Comment: From the askers question I read that he already tried what you provided in your answer: "`I set classpath to reference the jar file, but I get all sorts of symbol not found errors when I try to run my compile my own script. `" Your post sees to repeat him and claim it should work. From my point of view you've should have verified through questsions in comments what the asker actually did (downloaded exactly what?, configured how?, ...) to make sure he made something wrong. And in my opinion at least the how to configure is issing in your post, even if it's a mere -classpath "/pat/to/luck.jar"

Comment: If VTD-XML is your project, as your name and bio suggest, remember that **you must** say so in answers that link to or recommend it, or your answers may be construed as spam. Your answers are being picked up by the community spam detector bot because of this.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Your username has no bearing. You need to disclaim, in the body of the answer, that this is your software that you're recommending/linking to.